# Codename One - Collecting entropy

Tags: cryptography, codenameone, entropy

Is there some direct way (without writing platform-specific code) to collect some entropy from underlying system?

Do you have any plans to add cross-platform entropy collecting mechanism? It will be very useful feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our encryption support is all implemented via a [cn1lib](https://github.com/codenameone/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/) which isn't the latest and greatest either but it provides most of the basic stuff we need. We never went into that level of encryption/security when porting that library, if the native platforms support more secure randoms you can use a [native interface](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) to map to that and possibly also submit a pull request to the lib.